# npm start doesn't detect changes #React #Windows

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-start

Simply, react does not detect changes unless the batch job is ended and i restart the app using npm start
I went through the troubleshooting:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/troubleshooting

I am new to React and I struggle to understand all the terminology related to the webpack, watchers etc. It could be either one of these I am experiencing issues with.

The development server starts with no errors
The npm start executes with no errors
There's no errors in the dev tools in the console, all it says is
"log.js:24 [HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS..."

I followed this guide to create the react app
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

`npm version { 'my-app': '0.1.0', npm: '6.14.8', ares: '1.16.1', brotli: '1.0.9', cldr: '37.0', icu: '67.1', llhttp: '2.1.3', modules: '83', napi: '7', nghttp2: '1.41.0', node: '14.15.0', openssl: '1.1.1g', tz: '2020a', unicode: '13.0', uv: '1.40.0', v8: '8.4.371.19-node.17', zlib: '1.2.11' }`

System: Windows 10
Editor: Visual Studio Code (I read that it doesn't have safe write mode, so that shouldn't be a problem?)

I am not sure what else I can provide to solve an issue.

I appreciate any help,
Regards.